# Any free animation available for WPF?

Tags: wpf, animation

Being developer its very hard to designing and Animate the thing... Are there any animation libraries (like WPF themes) available out there for WPF ??

Answer (score 11):

Well even though I disagree with you because I am a developer and I am really enjoying the design/animation part in WPF.

Here are some Libraries and coding examples/controls for your use:

1)  [FluidKit](http://www.codeplex.com/fluidkit) (it is in source form )..

2 ) [Articles by Sacha Barber](http://www.codeproject.com/script/Articles/MemberArticles.aspx?amid=569009)   (check Sacha Barber's projects on [CodeProject.com](http://www.codeproject.com/script/Articles/MemberArticles.aspx?amid=569009) .. you will find a lot of interesting customized controls and animated ones.

3) [Dr. WPF](http://www.drwpf.com/blog/)  is another great contributor. He has some nice customized controls and animations.

4) [CodeProject search](http://www.codeproject.com/search.aspx?artkw=wpf+animation&sa_ao=False&sa_us=False&sa_so=17&sa_as=1%2c3&q=WPF+animation&doctypeid=1%3b2%3b3)

and just in case you never used CodeProject/ search... the link above lists a good amount of WPF animation tools/controls and even "tutorials" in case you felt like spending some of your time learning something new.

5) [Silverlight Carousel: Creating a Silverlight Control Displays Picture in an Interactive Carousel](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/silverlight/carousel.aspx?msg=2845588) : 3D image carousal, even though the project is for Silverlight but the control implementation is pretty much the same I believe.

**Edit:** Adding more links to whatever animated controls/animations I can find :)

Comment: your welcome :) .. don't hesitate to vote up.. or accept :D .. if u found them useful .. :D

Comment: I'll wait for some more response :)