# How to create left and right swipes in WPF using Mouse?

Tags: c#, wpf, swipe, swipe-gesture

I'm very new to C#.So, i'm trying create a simple swipe function in my WPF where if i swipe left or right, it goes to another wpf window. Please help me! I cannot find much resources online.

So my question is how to swipe using mouse in wpf application, so that i can switch between pages/window using mouse swipe.

[image: Sketch]

I'm just trying to do like an image Carousel. I have so far followed this [WPF image swipe to change image like in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11411955/wpf-image-swipe-to-change-image-like-in-ios)
But, it doesn't swipe but zooms in and out when mouse is moved.

Comment: Should this work on Desktop, UWP or xamarin?

Comment: Are You want this with touch screen or with mouse ?

Comment: @DanielW. Desktop

Comment: @ShubhamSahu Mouse

Comment: Using a mouse for this is a strange UI. Swiping is primarily a touch-based gesture.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add additional information. While you can *also* put it in comments, comments are considered temporary and should not be the only place that information exists that directly impacts the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am Using Pages but you can use window also.

1st. Create two Pages LeftPage.xaml, and RightPage.Xaml
and following code to MainWindow.xaml and MainWindows.xaml.cs

**XAML**

MainWindow

```
<Window x:Class="SOWPF.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"        
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SOWPF"
    mc:Ignorable="d" 
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800"
    MouseDown="Window_MouseDown" MouseMove="Window_MouseMove">
<Grid>
    <Frame x:Name="MainFrame" NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden" />
</Grid>
```

**C#**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    protected Point SwipeStart;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MainFrame.Source = new Uri("LeftPage.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
    }

    private void Window_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        SwipeStart = e.GetPosition(this);
    }

    private void Window_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
        {
            var Swipe = e.GetPosition(this);                

            //Swipe Left
            if (SwipeStart != null && Swipe.X > (SwipeStart.X + 200))
            {
                // OR Use Your Logic to switch between pages.
                MainFrame.Source = new Uri("LeftPage.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
            }

            //Swipe Right
            if (SwipeStart != null && Swipe.X < (SwipeStart.X - 200))
            {
                // OR Use Your Logic to switch between pages.
                MainFrame.Source = new Uri("RightPage.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
            }
        }
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

[image: Demo]

Comment: YOU SAVED MY LIFE !!! THANK YOU SO MUCH :D WORKS LIKE A CHARM!

Comment: Glad it works .. If you satisfied with answer you can mark it is an answer by click on tick button available left side of answer

Answer (score 1):

I've created a `Behavior` so that the whole thing can be done without the need for any code behind. The good thing of using a `Behavior` is that you can reuse it wherever in your solution, unit test it to ensure it does as you want or extend it's functionality.

**Main Window**

```
<Window x:Class="TestWpfApplication.MainWindowView"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
        xmlns:testWpfApplication="clr-namespace:TestWpfApplication"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" 
        Height="450" 
        Width="800">

    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <testWpfApplication:SwipeBehavior TargetContentControl="{Binding ElementName=MainContentControl}" LeftUserControl="{Binding Path=LeftControl}" RightUserControl="{Binding Path=RightControl}" />
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>

    <Grid>
        <ContentControl Name="MainContentControl" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**Main Window Code Behind**

```
using System.Windows;

namespace TestWpfApplication
{
    public partial class MainWindowView : Window
    {
        private readonly MainWindowViewModel _mainWindowViewModel = new MainWindowViewModel();

        public MainWindowView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            DataContext = _mainWindowViewModel;
        }
    }
}
```

**Swipe Behavior**

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Interactivity;

namespace TestWpfApplication
{
    public class SwipeBehavior : Behavior<Window>
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty TargetContentControlProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("TargetContentControl", typeof(ContentControl), typeof(SwipeBehavior), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));

        public static readonly DependencyProperty LeftUserControlProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("LeftUserControl", typeof(UserControl), typeof(SwipeBehavior), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));

        public static readonly DependencyProperty RightUserControlProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("RightUserControl", typeof(UserControl), typeof(SwipeBehavior), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));

        public static ContentControl GetTargetContentControl(DependencyObject dependencyObject)
        {
            return (ContentControl) dependencyObject.GetValue(TargetContentControlProperty);
        }

        public static void SetTargetContentControl(DependencyObject dependencyObject, ContentControl value)
        {
            dependencyObject.SetValue(TargetContentControlProperty, value);
        }

        public static ContentControl GetLeftUserControl(DependencyObject dependencyObject)
        {
            return (UserControl) dependencyObject.GetValue(LeftUserControlProperty);
        }

        public static void SetLeftUserControl(DependencyObject dependencyObject, UserControl value)
        {
            dependencyObject.SetValue(LeftUserControlProperty, value);
        }

        public static ContentControl GetRightUserControl(DependencyObject dependencyObject)
        {
            return (UserControl) dependencyObject.GetValue(RightUserControlProperty);
        }

        public static void SetRightUserControl(DependencyObject dependencyObject, UserControl value)
        {
            dependencyObject.SetValue(RightUserControlProperty, value);
        }

        private Point _swipeStart;

        protected override void OnAttached()
        {
            base.OnAttached();
            AssociatedObject.MouseDown += OnMouseDown;
            AssociatedObject.MouseMove += OnMouseMove;
        }

        private void OnMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            _swipeStart = e.GetPosition(AssociatedObject);
        }

        private void OnMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            var targetContentControl = GetValue(TargetContentControlProperty) as ContentControl;

            if (targetContentControl == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
            {
                var swipe = e.GetPosition(AssociatedObject);                

                //Swipe Left
                if (swipe.X > (_swipeStart.X + 200))
                {
                    // OR Use Your Logic to switch between pages.
                    targetContentControl.Content = new LeftControl();
                }

                //Swipe Right
                if (swipe.X < (_swipeStart.X - 200))
                {
                    // OR Use Your Logic to switch between pages.
                    targetContentControl.Content = new RightControl();
                }
            }

            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

**Main Window View Model**

```
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace TestWpfApplication
{
    internal class MainWindowViewModel
    {
        public UserControl LeftControl { get; } = new LeftControl();

        public UserControl RightControl { get; } = new RightControl();
    }
}
```

*Note:* The LeftControl & RightControl are WPF User Controls in this example. Also you must reference System.Window.Interactivity in your project in order to use the `Behavior` class